# Flutter how to load new screen by tap on navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created a custom bottom navigation bar for my app but I messed up my code. Right now its just shifting screen by true false value. I want to load screen but what I done is simple showing screen in body by bool.

My code

```
        bottomNavigationBar: CustomBottomNavigationBar(
          iconList: [
            'images/ichome.png',
            'images/icservice.png',
            'images/icstore.png',
            'images/Component 7 – 1@2x.png',
          ],
          iconList2: [
            'images/ichomeactive.png',
            'images/icserviceactive.png',
            'images/icstoreactive.png',
            'images/icaccount.png',
          ],
          onChange: (val) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedItem = val;
              print(val);
              if (val == 0) {
                setState(() {
                  home = true;
                  service = false;
                  shop = false;
                  account = false;
                });
              }
              if (val == 1) {
                home = false;
                service = true;
                shop = false;
                account = false;
              }
              if (val == 2) {
                home = false;
                service = false;
                shop = true;
                account = false;
              }
              if (val == 3) {
                home = false;
                service = false;
                shop = false;
                account = true;
              }
            });
          },
          defaultSelectedIndex: 0,
        ),
```

You can see on click I am changing bool value and in body show my widget. I know its wrong I do very stupid thing. That's why I need to know how I can load the page instead of just show and hide ? Also I need to show the navigation bar also on each page.

Comment: Try creating four different flutter widgets for the four pages. Have the same bottom navigation bar. Depending on which page you are in and where you want to go, you can re-route to that specific widget. Although, it would be better if you could reduce redundancy in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code of Navigation bar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: SettingView(),
    );
  }
}

class SettingView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingViewState createState() => _SettingViewState();
}

class _SettingViewState extends State<SettingView> {
  final tabs = [DashboardView(), NotificationView(), ProfileView()];

  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setState(() {});
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 40.0,
        elevation: 0,
        centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        title: Text("Navigation Bar"),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        selectedItemColor: Colors.white,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: InkResponse(
              focusColor: Colors.transparent,
              hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
              highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 10,
                ),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.dashboard,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            title: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 10,
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.notifications),
            ),
            title: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 10,
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.account_box),
            ),
            title: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.zero),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          )
        ],
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
      ),
      body: tabs[_currentIndex],
    );
  }
}

/*Dashboard*/
class DashboardView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Dashboard"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/*Notification*/
class NotificationView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Notification"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/*Profile*/
class ProfileView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text("Profile"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
    title: 'app name',
    home: HomeScreen(),
    routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
      '/route1': (BuildContext context) => FirstScreen(),
      '/route2': (BuildContext context) => SecondScreen(),
   },
 );
}
```

Create reusable navigation bar Widget and for selected content just tell navigator where it needs to bring you:

```
Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/route1');
```